# K&R: Define Line of Input - Understanding the Basics of Char Array

Tags: arrays, c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Exercise 1-18 in K&R (2nd edition, ANSI C) asks the reader to:

> Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

My question to the community is, can someone please clarify if "Line of Input" means input that contains both tab and blank characters, or just a line of input that has nothing but tabs and blank characters.

Look for help from an experienced developer that can help me understand if I am overthinking this or if there is a simpler solution to both the answer.

Comment: The key word there is "trailing" - meaning lines that end with spaces and tabs. Ex `"Hello world   "`  → `"Hello world"`. But the 2nd part means  to remove lines with nothing but tabs and spaces.

Comment: "Line of input" means just that - whatever string is returned by `fgets` or equivalent.  You can't make any assumptions about what it contains.  It may have any combination of tabs, blanks, other characters.  All tabs and blanks is certainly a possibility, and you would need to handle it correctly (by not outputting it).

Comment: A line of input is any sequence of characters followed by a newline character `'\n'`. The typical way to read a line of input is with `fgets`. However, a couple pages before that exercise, the book has the implementation of a function called `getline` that reads a line from stdin.

Comment: Thank you @user3386109, Nate, and Johnny. Appreciate your time and help with my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

A line of input is a sequence of characters ended by a '\n' character.
In this case, I assume that blank line refers to any combination of blanks and tabs, followed by a newline character.
An idea for solving the problem is to have states, and only pass to the output (using functions like printf and putchar) a sequence of tabs and blanks once you know there are more non-space characters in the same line.
Good luck with your learning!

Answer (score 0):

> please clarify if "Line of Input" means input that contains both tab and blank characters, or just a line of input that has nothing but tabs and blank characters.

C library defines *line* as

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.

So a *line of inputs* is **all** the characters up to and including a `'\n'`.  The line stops with the `'\n'` or *end of file*.  Thus its length is 0 or more and with a potential trailing `'\n'`.

---

Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input and save as a *string*.

Process the *string*, perhaps from the end, looking for tabs and spaces.